# How to only allow a certain amount of the same instance in Game Maker?

Tags: game-maker

I am creating a simple jump n' run game. For some reason my game sometimes spawns two instances of the same enemy on top of each other. So you can't tell there are two of him until he uses his attack where he shoots a barrage of bullets in random directions.

So now when the game spawns two of them, there are also twice as many bullets which makes the game too difficult to play.

I don't know what causes the game to spawn two. It only happens very rarely. I would just make it so that if there are two instances of the same enemy, it destroys one of them.

That would solve the problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! We can't help you, without seeing some code. This sounds like small bug, but you are trying to fix it in a way, that is not good.

Comment: You have the wrong solution; deleting one instance is really not the way to go. You should really find _why_ there are two instances created. I don't know game maker, but I would try and put a breakpoint in the constructor of the class, or on the code that creates it and start from there.

Comment: Well what really seems wierd to me is that even when I change the room the game now spawns two

Comment: Sorry, accidently press enter on the recent post. I now made it so that when two enemy spwan ontop of each other they just disappear and trigger a different attack for the main boss. These said enemys are summoned by that boss enemy. The new attack that I gave the boss (wich only happens when two enemys spawn ontop of each other) teleports the player to an entierly different room. And the wierd thing is that now sometimes the Game spawns two players... that doesn't make any sense to me anymore.

Comment: I understand that this might not be the ideal solution to this problem, but it might also come in handy for the future

Comment: Actually, it would be a better idea to control the number of instances created in the first place. Also, it would be nice to know what's the "some reason" multiple enemies are created, maybe in the form of GML code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your question but it is NOT how you should solve your problem. I noticed in the comments that you are aware of that and would like this solution anyway.

Put this in the step event of an object that always exists when you want this to happen:

```
if (instance_number(OBJECT) > MAX_OBJECTS) {
     with (instance_find(OBJECT, MAX_OBJECTS)) {
           instance_destroy()
     }
}
```

Where MAX_OBJECTS is the maximum number of instances allowed to exist and OBJECT is the name of the object you are checking for. This will destroy the last created instance just after it is created.

Notice that this is not how you should solve this problem, you should simply stop making more of an object once you hit the limit, but this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A way you could solve it is by checking how many of the object that exist int the create event.

So for example if you put this code in the create event

```
if(instance_number(OBJECT) >= MAX_OBJECTS)
{
   instance_destroy()
}
```

OBJECT Is the object type that you are looking for, in this example it should be the same object as the create even it is put in.
MAX_OBJECTS Is the amount of objects that should be allowed.

This is not maybe the best way to do it to solve your cause you haven't really solved that problem problem, just fixed the symptom but this way works also if you for some reason wan't to limit the amount of one object and because it is in the create event it will only run when needed.